# vector constructor / destructor calls

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

class A {
public:
  int i;
  A(int i=0):i(i) {
    cout << "A::A() called" << endl;
  }
  ~A() {
    cout << "A::~A() called" << endl;
  }

};

int main() {
  vector<A> *a = new vector<A>(3);
  delete a;
}
```

The program prints:

```
A::A() called
A::~A() called
A::~A() called
A::~A() called
A::~A() called
```

Why do I see one constructor and four destructors called ?

I am using g++ 4.8.4.

Comment: Copy constructors being called

Comment: That output [is wrong](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dcfb98936905392) for the above snippet you listed

Comment: @WhiZTiM This is not true: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ecb4852b136545d That output is expected to c++03

Comment: @Amadeus, You are right. :-). I was wrong, I assumed latest `C++` version by `C++` tag.

Comment: @M.M you're right; I 've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct vector of three instances of A, it is filled with default value. Default value is taken from vector constructor argument. You didn't provide one, so it is constructed either by constructor without arguments or by constructor with default argument values. You provided the latter, so the first constructor call.

All three elements are copy-constructed, so no call to your constructor.

Then the default value instance is destroyed, so the first destructor.

Then you delete the vector, which deletes all three instances, calling destructor three times.

Try printing value of `this` in the functions to try for yourself or try this sample: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/903fa70484f5c3bc

Comment: Adding `A(const A& o) { cout << "copy-constructor on" << this << endl; }` confirms this answer.

Comment: Note: C++11 outlawed the practice of copy-constructing vector entries as seen in OP code, now it is required that each entry be default-constructed when the caller didn't supply initializers.